# How to detect increase in requests/sec rate?

Tags: algorithm, bigdata

I am trying to process clicks streams for different links in real time. Each click gets logged into a database. For most of the links the number of clicks/min is more or less constant (e.g. < 50). However, a handful of them get 1000-2000/min but only for a short period of time.

I want to detect when I am starting to see such a high traffic click stream since I want to defer and batch database updates for these streams instead of performing them in real-time.

I've been playing with a number of approaches but without good results. This looks like a standard math problem or queue management problem to me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you managed to find the solution? i am facing same sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the time you insert each click, also calculate the number of clicks over the past minute and insert that.  Then you can just query for events where the rate is high enough.

For example (pseudocode):

```
proc record_click
    insert into click_log (current_time, event_info)
    insert into click_rates (current_time, 
        (select count(*) from click_log where time > current_time - 1 minute))
```

If you don't want to do it at the time of inserting the click, you can calculate that value later, but that will be a potentially huge data set to chew through, rather than just your ~50 records at each click time.

```
create view click_rates as
    select event_time, count(*) as rate
    from click_events e1, click_events e2
    where e2.event_time between e1.event_time - interval '1 minute' and e1.event_time
    group by e1.event_time
```

Comment: This will give me the click_rate but what I'm after is how I detect a sharp increase in the click rate in real time.

Comment: Then you just check if the current click rate is greater than the average over the past hour, or something like that.   Or take a derivative (somehow) and see where the value of that is above some threshold.  I'm sure a DFT could be useful also, but exactly how escapes me at the moment.